# Cannot resolve symbol (Java 8) lambdas

Tags: lambda, java-8

I'm kinda new to lambdas in Java 8.
Here is a short snippet of my code:

```
public void analyzeQueries() {
  while (queries.size() > 0) {
    int rating;
    InvestmentQuery query = getFirstPriority(queries);
    RatingCacheElement cacheElement = stockToRating.get(x -> x.stockID == query.stockID);

    if (cacheElement != null)
      rating = cacheElement.rating;
    else {
      rating = calculateRating(query.stockID);
      stockToRating.add(new RatingCacheElement(query.stockID, rating));
    }
    if (rating > 80)
      stockTrader.enqueueStock(query);
  }
}
```

The complier output says "Error:(23, 54) java: incompatible types: int is not a functional interface".
`x.stockID` is also being flagged with "Cannot resolve symbol".
Using Android Studio 2.3.3, Gradle 1.14.1.

Comment: What is the type of `stockToRating`?

Comment: Here's how stockToRating is defined `private List stockToRating = new ArrayList<RatingCacheElement>();`

Comment: Hmm. It seems like it would be better to use a map, here.

Comment: Okay... but I would like to get it to work with an arraylist. Map would definitely work, but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your snippet it seems that `stockToRating` is a `List<RatingCacheElement>`. The [`List.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) method accepts `int` (that is, the index of list element). If you want to find an element by condition, consider using Stream API:

```
RatingCacheElement cacheElement = stockToRating.stream()
   .filter(x -> x.stockID == query.stockID).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Here you say to filter a stream of list items by condition, then find the first element matching the filter or return null if nothing is found.

Comment: Tried as suggested @Tagir Valeev. However, I get a different message `Unchecked call to orElse() as a member of raw type 'java.util.Optional'`. Note also that `x.stockID` has remained red in color.

Comment: @bobuntu, seems that your `stockToRating` is declared simply as `List`, not as `List<RatingCacheElement>`. If not, please edit the question to include the whole source code.

Comment: I had initially done so, but in the process of debugging I simply went for `List`. Following your suggestion has fixed the problem, thank you!